# Is there a way that only class that inherits a class sees its members. They are both in the same package

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

For example we have three classes.

Class A which have some members
Class B which extends class A
and we got main class
And they are all in the same package !

Is there any way that members in class A could only be accessible in class B beacuse class B extends class A.

If we use private members in class A then class B cant see members which we inherits.

But if we use public members in class A then both classes main and b can see it's members.

Comment: Go read about access modifiers (private, protected, public)

Comment: Problem is i guess then because all three classes are in the same package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you can't do this. Regardless if you define your field `protected` or use no modifier, your class `B` and your `Main` class will always be able to access the field.

The simple solution here would be to move your class `A` to a sub-package and declare the field `protected`. This way only sub-classes of `A` and classes in the sub-package will be able to access the field.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. So answer is it cant be done. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Use "**protected**" access modifier

**protected** : Only the current class and subclasses (and sometimes also same-package classes) of this class will have access to the field or method.

Comment: Forgot to mention that classes are in the same package. Edited my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `protected` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Class A is a SuperClass of Class B,
You can access from the superclass from anywhere, creating an object of that class type and whether the methods of this are public . if they are private so only you can access them from the implementation of the classe , although not quite understand what you mean ... explain yourself a little better

protected is a type of class that its functionality is being published for members of the same class type , and private for all other classes.

Comment: she says only the child class should access the members of its parent class